# How to get number of days between two months in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am doing a project called employee leave management in python, in this i want to get difference between number of days between two dates.

My Scenario :
 If employee doesnt take leave for particular month means than he will have a bucket call accumulated leave in that bucket one leave will get added, if he took leave means then bucket count will be '0', it will be generated in every month starting then it will calculate for previous months. A scenario like if HR  forget's to generate leave for month of "March" and again he is coming in may and he is generating . The last generated date is "March 15th" if he clicks generate button in may 29 means the leave should calculate from "March 16" to "May 29" how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> d1 = date(2017,3,16)
>>> d2 = date(2017,5,29)
>>> abs(d1 - d2).days
74
```